# How to Kubernetes Cloud like GKE , EKS,.. allocation external ip for Service with Type Loadbacer in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I just new in K8s. I try to self deploy k8s cloud in internal company server. And I have question how to I setup my K8s can allocation External IP for Service with Loabalancer. May you tell you how it work in GKE or EKS?

Comment: What I mean how to EKS or GKE  behind the scenes allocation ip, what is a mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated base on your comment.

`What I mean how to EKS or GKE behind the scenes allocation ip, what is a mechanism?`

Here's the [EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html) version and here's the [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/gke-address-management-overview) version. It's a complex thing, suggest you use these materials as the starting point before diving into technical details (which previous answer provided you the source). In case you thought of on-premises k8s cluster, it depends on the CNI  that you will use, a well known CNI is [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/get-started-ip-addresses).

Answer (score 0):

In GKE you can define [services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) to expose or to make accessible the applications defined in the cluster. There are several kinds of services one of them is a [LoadBalancer service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_loadbalancer), this can have an external IP address.